# Change the validity period on existing android keystore certificate

Tags: android, xamarin, certificate, keystroke

I have already create a keystore and I have already distribute my app via local servers. Now I want to publish my app to the Play Store.
Unfortunately, when I create the keystore I set the validity period to 10 years, which expires too soon (according to the message I got when I try to upload the apk to the google play console). Because the app is already distributed to some devices, if I create a new keystore, the already installed apps want be able to update via the Playstore due to the difference of the keystore. So my question is... is there a way to increase the duration to my existing key store, and if it is, how?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As far as I know you cannot change the expiration time. From what I understand you have distributed the app only to some devices, so you can create a new one. Also 10 years period is quite a long time IMO

Comment: Thanks @NongthonbamTonthoi! I'll do that as a final solution. Right now I am looking if there is a way to override this policy about the certificate use it anyway...